# css position relative differentiates from absolute

Tags: css, css-position

I got troubles using relative positions. Following code in css:

```
#background
{
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

#p1 
{
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

In my opinion, the upper-left corner from background and p1 should be even. But it simply doesn't. I would say it is pushed roughly +50px to the right and bottom. How come and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Position absolute doesn't have the same behavior as relative .... the difference can be based on the relative parent of the absolute element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position:absolute` means that it is being positioned based on the top-left corner of the ancestor which is either a parent which has a position specification, or the `<body>` element itself if there isn't any. However, `position:relative` means that it is being positioned based on the location it would normally be taking were it not being relocated (ie, normal position + offset). If your code is something like:

```
<div id="background"><div id="p1">...</div></div>
```

Then that means that `background` should be positioned at the top-left corner (plus the offsets), but that `p1` should be 100 pixels down and to the right of the corner of its parent, `background`.

**EDIT:** Fixed the definitions regarding the two positions.